# How to change the default font of gVim

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-registry, gvim

#### Edit: I moved the original question to ['The docked gVim in Windows 7 jumps upon tab switch'](https://superuser.com/questions/584844/the-docked-gvim-in-windows-7-jumps-upon-tab-switch)

After struggling with my `.vimrc`, I am resorting to setting the font from windows registry instead, because without the `guifont` in .vimrc, everything works fine. The only registry mentioned I found was,

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
```

This is for MS command line, but it was not what I was looking for. Currently gVim is set to `Fixedsys` by default. The search though the registry for value `fixedsys` returned no result. My gut feeling is that one can change it through the registry setting. Is there such registry value?

Comment: This may not be exactly what you want, but you might consider using standard vim (non-gui) in Windows. Using more high quality console replacement such as [console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) will give you the usual VIM experience, and you should be able to use any font you like.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? More specifics on what happens versus what you expect, what sequence of commands you are using to reload the file, which settings are in `vimrc` versus `gvimrc`, stuff like that. If you are not already putting your gui initialization in a separate `gvimrc`, try that first.

Comment: @Fopedush I already use non-gui vim through `mintty`, but the advantage of gVim is `+clientserver` option. Also if you use `vimperator` with firefox, you can also edit text fields easily with `ctrl-i` shortcut. This is not possible with `vim`.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I clarified the question. I do not think it is the conflict with the .vimrc (mine is quite big) and I did test it thoroughly. The auto source of .vimrc and `guifont` is all it takes to trigger the behavior.

Comment: Thanks. A good next step would be to create a minimal `vimrc` that reproduces the problem. Does the window become undocked if you use a `vimrc` that contains nothing but a `guifont` setting?

Comment: Also, you might have better luck asking "how to fix this?" rather than "how to set this in the registry?" in case there's a better solution, or if the problem also happens to people on non-Windows version of vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font was hardcoded into the binary of gvim.exe and vim.exe. I just search and fine through the binary for 'Fixedsys'. I changed that portion to with the name of font I wanted and it was all good. Any editor will do, but I used another vim (non-gui, cygwin) in this case, because vim is very good for opening a massive file. I did not need to recompile

Comment: Did you recompile it or hack the binary? Any details you could offer to help people who want to accomplish the same thing?